# pip.exe is missing but pip library still exist

Tags: python, pip

When I was executing `pip install`, there was an error that `pip` command is not recognized. Thus, I checked the Scripts file content by executing dir and it showed [no pip.exe there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgiJq.png)

I've been using `pip` with no problem before and I remember there has always a pip.exe file there. So, I figured my `pip` is deleted somehow but in site-packages, I can clearly see that [it's there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nuzj.png) and I checked that indeed, I installed `pip` with python before.

I had made sure my PATH is correct several times, but cmd still show the error.
I can still use `python -m pip install` to install libraries but I'm still curious how did the pip.exe disappear (or maybe not)? If it does, how do I make it appear again?

For additional detail, when I execute `where pip` it said `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: If it's python 3 then you should have installed pip 3 so try **pip3 install**

Comment: Could be that pip3 is the command for the executable. `pip3 install` as just a test

Comment: No, it's the same. `pip3` is not even in the site-package.

Comment: If you are sure the copy of `pip.exe` that you have is correct (`pip --version` from that folder) then copy it to `Scripts`. Sounds like an unintended drag'n'drop.

Comment: @BoarGules Well, I did found a copy of a `pip.exe` in another folder and tried to copy it. But `pip --version` shows it still display the earlier folder directory. So, any `pip` command I do will be implemeted in the earlier folder.  Can I somehow manipulate it to make it work on my intended folder?

Comment: What does `where pip` say?

Comment: And I meant to execute `pip --version`  *from the folder in `site-packages` where you see it.* Navigate there first. The point is to find out the version of *that* file, not the version of whatever instance is first in your path. `pip.exe` belongs in `Scripts`, where every Python installation since 3.4 puts it, because it is part of the official Python distribution: PEP453.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I've made a fix by just reinstalling `pip`. I guess was just being too disgruntled by this disappearing pip mystery and didn't think that I could re-installed it.